# RSS feed in Core Data crash

Tags: ios, core-data, rss, tableview

I created an RSS reader for a blog. I am retrieving the articles of the blog and am filling a `UITableView` with them in a navigation controller. When a user taps in a row, a web view comes up with the original article on the blog. I use Core Data in order to save the title, link and date of the articles with the following code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
rssFeed = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RSS" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [rssFeed setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
    [rssFeed setValue:link forKey:@"link"];
    [rssFeed setValue:date forKey:@"date"];
```

Then I call it with the following code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"RSS"];
self.feedArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
if ([_feedArray count] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"No matches");
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [_feedArray count]; i++)
    {
        matches = _feedArray[i];
    }
}
```

If I print the `feedArray` in the table view, the results are not so clear. I get something like `null` between the articles, and they aren't in the right order. Can anyone help me understand what happens?

And the error message:

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 25 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   24]'**

Comment: The error message is quite clear - you have tried to read element 26 from an array with 25 elements. What line line does this occur in?  You didn't specify a sort order in your fetch request, so the order isn't guaranteed

Comment: Paulw, I edited my question with a new part that i tried but the error remains. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that is the loop that it is crashing in?  It looks alright, if slightly pointless as it simply overwrites matches with every iteration.  It is the same as saying `matches=[_feedArray lastObject];`

Comment: I think that the problem is that every time i run the app my core data table writes the same data in the database. So the next time my table view tries to read the same values and add them in the cells. Here i think is the problem. I need to figure how to not add the same feeds in the table view